# Configurable item not changing price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

Been beating my head for a few days on this. When viewing a configurable product on the front end, select options, the price does not change to the price configured on the simple products.

Is this a magento config setting or a CSS config or ...?

It worked at one point a couple weeks ago but I don't know what has changed.

Configurable item has all associated items associated.

[image: Configurable item has all associated items associated.]

[image: Used to show a range here. This is the Grid View]

*[![This is the product view. Before selecting option it would show a range and selecting the options in the picture would show the actual price. This set should be $22][3]][3]*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have never used the Super Attribute settings except in testing. IT works there but does not display the price range like it used to.

Comment: I also just realized this may have changed when I did the latest round of updates. Wonder if there was something in there that affected this behavior.

Comment: Are you using a custom template (other than Magento's out of the box templates)?

Comment: B.t.w. image no. 3 went missing... Could you edit the question and add it again?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug, it's a feature.
For some reason that I'm missing, Magento does not use the prices for simple products inside a configurable product.
You can only set for the configurable options, relative prices to the configurable product.
here is an example.
You can have a product called 'T-shirt' with configurable size and color.
Let's say the configurable product has the price 12.00.
If your XL-black simple t-shirt has the price 13.00 you will still see 12.00 when adding it to the cart.
But what you can do is to assign to the black attribute and extra charge of `+1`. But this means that all black shirts in the configurable product will have an extra charge of +1.
You can also assign a +2 to the XL shirts, but this means that all xl shirts will have that extra +2.

if you add an extra charge for both xl and black (as described above) then the xl-black t-shirt will have the price 12+1+2 = 15.
The extra charge support negative values also.
I don't know who took this decision, I don't understand it either, but this is how it works out of the box.
If you want to use the simple product prices I can recommend you this extension: [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html). I haven't used it, but I see it's very popular. (and it's free)

Comment: The latest version that is compatible with is 1.5, does it work with 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that most of the time this issue comes when you are using 3rd party themes, which has either their own `price.html` or `option.phtml`. So make sure you debug from where the module output is coming. All the prices or options PHTML files should be coming from the same theme directories. Or if they don't, it should be configured to work that way.